# drop down menu using css

Tags: css, menu, using

I built a menu using li and ul but when I cannot click the sub menu when I hover my mouse over the menu. The sub menu appears when hovering my mouse over the menu but when I move the mouse to click the sub menu, it immediately disappears. Here is my code

```
<div id="navbar">
        <ul>
            <!-- The strange spacing herein prevents an IE6 whitespace bug. -->
            <li><span><a href="#">Shop</a></span>

            </li>
            <li>
                <span><a href="#">Top menu</a></span>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <span><a href="#">Sub menu</a></span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><span><a href="#">Test1</a></span>

            </li>
            <li><span><a href="#">Test2</a></span>

            </li>
        </ul>
</div>

#navbar li ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    width: 10em;

    /* Width to help Opera out */
    background-color: #b5cd96;
}

#navbar ul li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: He only uses CSS.. and it can be perfectly done with CSS, so your javascript comment is not relevant @Lowkase

Comment: I'm not using Javascript.

Comment: I made a Jsfiddle for this, but I cant see the problem, within the Jsfiddle, it all works fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/TteJ4/. So can you show us the page you re working on. Cause in this case I doubt the code up there is your problem.

Comment: It is working now. I had some extra css code that was conflicting with my menu. Thanks for your help.